# jquery append usage without generating HTML in strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build some list elements using jQuery append(...) but I do not seem to get the syntax correct. I have come part way (with the correct output), but I am sure that there is a better way to use the function that does not require my building HTML directly from strings.

My desired result...

```
<a href='...;'>
  <div>Wigan</div>
  <div style="font-size: 8px">Wigan, null, NaN</div>
</a>
```

My JavaScript...

```
var result = $("<a>", {href: "..."});
result.append("<div>"+ results[index].Region + "</div>");
result.append("<div style = \" font-size: 8px\">" + results[index].District + ", " + results[index].Postcode + ", " + +results[index].CountryCode + "</div>");
```

What I have above works, but how do I group the append calls and the content to build this up without simply creating the strings as I do above?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into something like [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) to template out repeated elements like this?

Comment: @BrianMuenzenmeyer: No, until now I had never heard of it. If possible, I would prefer to avoid adding new frameworks at this time though as I know that I can achieve what I need with jQuery even if I end up doing it the way I have shown above. Thanks though.

Comment: Understandable. template frameworks give you a lot of power - but what TrueBlueAussie describes below would work in a bind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

`result.append($('<div>').html(results[index].Region), $('<div>',{ style:' ...' }));`

or

`$('<div>').html(results[index].Region).appendTo(result)`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a template addin (like moustache) here is a simple trick:

Put your template in a dummy script block with an unknown type

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
        <a href='...;'><div>{{name}}</div><div style="font-size: 8px">{{name}}{{someother}}</div></a>
</script>
```

and use as if it was a plain HTML string. Use replace to insert your values into any placeholders:

```
var html = $('#template').html().replace(/{{name}}/g, myname).replace(/{{someother}}/g, someother)
```

The result is ready to append/insert etc into the DOM.

Notes:

- I used the moustache-style markers for this example, but anything unique will do to match.
- This makes editing your template WYSIWYG/obvious so maintenance is easier.

Comment: I like what you have done there, but for consistency with the way the application is currently built I have used @Veo's solution instead. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Robins: Your call. You asked for a *better* way (and there are several) :)

Comment: Yeah that's the problem with these types of questions. Lots of ways to skin a cat and it boils down to personal taste.